# USB connector always reverse to connections on the IC

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, usb, uart

I'm looking to add an interface IC on to my PCB.  The chip will interface through a USB B Micro connector. What I don't understand is why all the ICs I have found are designed so that the D+ and D- have to cross over. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

This is me coming out of the connector and into the ESD protection:

[image]

Then after this to connect to the IC it means the wires have to cross over. I have found this with a lot of ICs:

[image]

Comment: Note that if you were using a through hole connector mounted on the other side, then the pin ordering would be correct. My guess is that the pinout was just based on the easiest routing from the die to the package and not much thought was given to the ordering. Dealing with pin order issues is bread and butter stuff for PCB designers.

Comment: I'm struggling to find any though hole connectors, what about if I put the connector on the bottom and came out the pads into VIAs up to the top layer then into the components, I was just trying to avoid using VIAs as didn't want that to effect data or cause any EMI, EMC issue

Comment: vias are no big deal for USB 2.0; The signal is not that fast. If I were you, I'd just drop a via near the IC and call it a day. If you don't believe me, google "USB 2.0 pin header" and "USB 3.0 pin header". These monstrosities (for impedance and signal integrity) are used to connect the motherboard to the front panel in every desktop PC. The 3.0 version caries much faster signals, than your D+/D-, yet it still passes EMC :)

Comment: What is the part number of the IC? An MCU *may* give you the option to reposition the pins.

Comment: @Rodo that part looks more like one of the SiLabs bridges in QFN28 rather than MCU. Also, I've never seen USB signals multiplexed to different pins before. I suspect chip designers want to keep those somewhere in the dark corner of the silicone, as far from other stuff as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think your complaint is without merit.

There are four possible options for connector placement: through hole and SMD, both on top or bottom of the PCB. So, any order of chip pins directly corresponds to at least half of these. And that's really the best they can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try designing the connector and IC to be on separate sides of the PWB. Your other option is to find a different IC that does what you want and has the pins on the opposite order.